# TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I have hit a problem. Program must get ip addresses frome txt file and came for each one ip. Check logging saccessful or not.
I have no idea why in this simple code I have a problem.

```
from termcolor import colored
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


myfile = [p.rstrip() for p in open('test.txt')]

for ip in myfile:

    driver = webdriver.Chrome('./lib/chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get("http://admin:password@" + ip)
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located(By.XPATH, ".//*/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]")
        )
    except TimeoutException:
        print(colored(ip + " except timeout error", "red"))

    else:
        print(colored(ip + " is OK", "green"))
    finally:
        driver.quit()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "E:/GS/Py/wifiproject/dwl3200.py", line 21, in <module>
   EC.presence_of_element_located(By.XPATH, ".//*/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]")
    TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use as

```
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ".//*/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]")))
```

You should provide `By.locator` and actual locator expression as tuple of arguments but not as two separate arguments